# What is Poly Scriptura?

Tags: scriptures, authority

I'm not sure if this has been asked,

I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXFgeoAC1Fo) on YouTube where the person in the video mentions "Poly Scriptura" at about 17:28, I have tried to look it up just to get the basic information on it and all that comes up in the search results is "Sola Scriptura"

Can someone please tell me what Poly Scriptura is?

Thanks and God bless.

Comment: Can you please link to the video and point out exactly when in the video the phrase occurs? We'd need context to give a correct answer.

Comment: The link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXFgeoAC1fo and it's mentioned near the end of the video.

Comment: @disciple I just checked the link and it worked just fine.

Comment: At about 17:28. The closed captioning said "poly stripped". I'm pretty sure he was thinking both of "many" ("poly" in Greek) scriptures AND of the term "sola scriptura" at the same time. It would be a good idea to add the link and the exact time to the question. I hope someone else will listen carefully to this and at least say what they think. I do think it was a slip of the tongue, so is purely a matter of opinion exactly what he intended to say.

Comment: @disciple I agree with you. It would be nice if there can be some clarification on what he said and meant. You’re right about the time in the video, and a minute later he says, “You’ve got multiple authorities, which means you have no authority.” What does he mean there?

Comment: There was a comment with a correct video link, but it's gone now and I can't find the video. You need to edit the address of the video and the time into your question so others can see the context. This is not a good place for discussions, but if you have a question about biblical authority I may be able to help you find basic references and clarify your question. I suggest you visit the [tour] and [help] to understand this site better.

Comment: @Netdude21 We have lost the link to the video. If you remember some details I will search for it and hopefully be able to edit it into your question. If you can still fetch the video, giving me the title and/or speaker should be enough. I cannot play the video using the link in your comment, and I assume no one else but (possibly) you can either.

Comment: @disciple The video is titled, "The Differences Between the King James Version and Modern Translations of the Bible Part 4" The speaker is Pastor Steve Waldron of New Life Pentecostal Church of Albany, GA.

Comment: "if you have multiple authorities, you have no authority". Research Biblical authority if you want to understand better, you may have several questions. Essentially he is saying you need to hear a single voice or you can't trust it. I don't know what was wrong with your link, it looks identical but didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "Poly" is a Greek word, meaning 'many'.
"Scriptura" is a Latin word, meaning 'scripture'.
Put these words together and we get the phrase 'many scriptures'. The  phrase "Poly Scriptura" would therefore refer to exactly that; be it all the 66 books in the Bible; the Bible & other books, such as the writings of the early church fathers; or, as in the Youtube video, the many different available Bible translations.

I found the below paragraph on this [site](https://hipandthigh.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/the-exclusivity-argument-2/). The author is rebutting "King James Onlyism"; that King James is the only acceptable Bible version and "sola-scriptura", and that all other Bible versions are "poly-scriptura".

> Most of the time, but not always, he tends to become agitated when I ask this, because it puts him on the defense. He is attempting to argue for God’s Word being found exclusively in one English translation.  However, it is his burden to demonstrate with reason why I must abandon my favored, non-KJV translation because it doesn’t fit the qualifications of infallible, inerrant, and so forth.  Now, he can chide and mock me by saying I believe in poly-scriptura not sola scriptura or what ever, but he is still in the position of establishing why his view of the biblical text is correct and mine is in error.

Comment: +1 I yield to your superior google-fu. Full disclosure: I used DDG and when I put "poly scriptura" in quotes, it found the same page -- but only a few hits.

Comment: In the mentioned YouTube film the author applies the phrase 'Sola Scriptura' to his, and many others, favoured version of the Bible; the King James Version. Although, 'Sola Scriptura' is a theological doctrine, held by especially protestant  Christians, that the written word (the Bible) has authority over tradition, irrespective of version. It was Martin Luther, who came up with the concept of 'Sola Scriptura' . He applied it to his German translation of the Bible. This Bible included the 'Old Testament Apocrypha', and was translated directly from the original text. (Wikipedia)

Comment: @Constantthin So, if I say that I read two different translations of the Bible (The NIV and the NLT) and like them that I'm applying "Poly Scriptura" to them, even though the verses say the same thing?
 
Galatians 2:20 comes to mind, they are worded pretty much the same in both translations mentioned above.

Comment: @Netdude21. The phrase "Poly Scriptura" is a somewhat new concept that probably can mean whatever you want it to mean, depending on where you come from. To me it would mean a shortcut, and a time saving 'device', for Bible students who don't know Greek or Hebrew, since the authors of the various Bible translations already have done the tedious ground work for us. I find "Bible Hub" being the perfect tool in this regard.